# AngularJS accessing parent controller properties from modal controller - resolve vs $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Learning AngularJS is a Work In Progress for me so I just want to understand why/when we should use one over another in particular case below. Is it just matter of taste or more than that? See examples below.

In both cases, when user clicks *OK* button, `create()` function of parent controller is called from child controller.

**RESOLVE STYLE**

**CreateController**

```
...

var vm = this;

vm.create = create;

function create() {
    console.log('Created!');
}

vm.openCreateModal = function() {
    vm.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        ...
        resolve: {
            create: function() {
                return create;
            },
            // Others if any
        }
    });
}

...
```

**CreateModalController**

```
...

vm.ok = function() {
    create();
    $uibModalInstance.close('ok');
};

...
```

**SCOPE STYLE**

**CreateController**

```
...

var vm = this;

vm.create = create;

function create() {
    console.log('Created!');
}

vm.openCreateModal = function() {
    vm.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        ...
        scope: $scope,
        resolve: {
        }
    });
}

...
```

**CreateModalController**

```
...

vm.ok = function() {
    $scope.$parent.vm.create();
    $uibModalInstance.close('ok');
};

...
```

**Update**

The actual reason why I ask this question is, accessining/injecting parent/root/container like objects of one service/controller in/to another controller/service is considered as a "bad practise" in some languages/frameworks I use.

Comment: Usage of `$parent` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of a deeper problem. The `resolve` property is more versatile and robust because it can be different for each instance of the modal. It can also be resolved with a promise.

Comment: @georgeawg I added "Update" section to explain why I came up with this question. You stepped right on it! I just didn't like `$scope.$parent...` bit for some reason. I just need to wait and see what others say about it.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of `resolve` is that it will run that first before initializing the rest of your code. Generally you would use `resolve` in your `routing` like so:

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: "views/view.html",
            caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
            resolve: {
                load: function() {
                    localStorage['Location'] = "/View";
                }
            }
        })
```

In the above example `resolve` will fire the `load function` before my controller is ever initialized. On the other hand `scope` is used to bind directly to something in a controller or directive. You should use `scope` when triggering functions and binding to values between controllers and directives.

To add to this based on the comments below, if the `resolve` fails it will reject the modal and the window will not open.

Comment: The OP is asking about the `resolve` property in the [UI-Bootstrap Modal Directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal).

Comment: This is the right answer, however it's worth mentioning that if the resolve fails (the promise rejects) the transition will be canceled and the modal will not show. this pattern is very common in angular.

Comment: I added that to my answer. @georgeawg I know he was talking about the bootstrap modal. I was just providing an example of how resolve works in Angularjs and when to use it vs scope like the OP asked.

Comment: This answer explains what `resolve` does in route config, but does not answer the question `"... why/when we should use one over another [with UI-Bootstrap Modal] ..."`

Comment: The answer still gives an explanation. resolve should be used to run code before doing a specific action like opening a window or initializing a controller or directive. It is still pertinent to the question being asked. It is just using routing as an example.